# Formal term for pushing down the hourly rate by letting applicants undercut each other

Tags: word-request, expressions

Sometimes (a.k.a. pretty much every time for some), when a company looks for a contractor, the recruiter will inquire about the expected hourly rate. While there may be a few valid reasons to do so (we don't need to list nor discuss those here), it's frequently, at least partially, being used to lower the cost. (It rarely works for a skilled professional but that's beside the point.)

In Swedish, we have an expression for it, which I assumed was directly translatable to English: *rate pressure* or *salary suppression*.

When I used it recently, trying to explain to a recruiter that I'm not willing to disclose my expected hourly rate (for the very reason of **not** promote the anti-pattern), they seemed not to understand what I mean.

Intuitively, I'd chalk it up to disability of understanding if the understanding has undesired implications. However, I want to be humble and prefer to verify that it isn't me Swedishifying up the message.

What is a proper, formal and recognized term for said phenomenon?